Why does my NestJS seeding script want other modules?
I have a NestJS app and I want to create a seeding script for status.  Here is my script:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';
import { Status } from '../../status/entities/status.entity';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

async function seed() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);

  const dataSource = app.get(DataSource);

  const statusRepository = dataSource.getRepository(Status);

  const statuses = [
    { name: 'Pending', codeStub: 'PENDING' },
    { name: 'Approved', codeStub: 'APPROVED' },
    { name: 'Processing', codeStub: 'PROCESSING' },
    { name: 'Completed', codeStub: 'COMPLETED' },
  ];

  await statusRepository.upsert(statuses, ['codeStub']);


  console.log('Statuses have been seeded');
  await app.close();
}

seed().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});

The script above resides in /src/database/seeds.  The Status entity links to one other entity, which then goes on to link to other entities etc.
When I run the above script using the command below I get a lot of messages stating that modules cannot be found.  These modules are not required for the status and in some cases are not directly associated with the status.
npx ts-node src/database/seeds/status.seed.ts

I'm not entirely sure why the seed script needs them and how to overcome the issue?

Adding actual errors would make this easier to help you debug

btw if this is just a seeding script, why are you loading the whole AppModule? I'd write another module instead
